# Historically Significant 3D Bicubic Patch Data?

Tags: 3d

[image: milk jug from thesis]

The little milk pitcher / jug in [Martin Newell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Newell_(computer_scientist))'s 1975 PhD thesis [“The Utilization of Procedure Models in Digital Image Synthesis”](https://collections.lib.utah.edu/ark:/87278/s6hh73p6), does anybody have the bicubic patch data for it?  The teapot's data ([in several early versions](http://www.holmes3d.net/graphics/teapot/)) is well-distributed of course, [the spoon and cup/saucer are downloadable](https://github.com/rm-hull/newell-teapot) from a few repositories.  But (so far) [I can't find the milk jug's](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-propose-an-addition-to-the-extra-objects-add-on/1351462/16).

Is it lost forever, or is somebody out there willing / able to make it available?

[image: Figure 29 Table Setting]

**Edited to add:**  for the purposes of the bounty I need patch data that when added properly to add_mesh_teapot.py produces a mesh substantially similar to “Figure 26  Meshes Defining a Jug” above, with [provenance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provenance) (at minimum, a description of how the data came into the answerer's possession that won't be significantly contradicted).

[image]

Above image is a screenshot of [Blender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)) using [a version of add_mesh_teapot.py that's had the teacup & saucer patch data added to it](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-propose-an-addition-to-the-extra-objects-add-on/1351462/22).

Comment: I don't know where the data can be found, but it seems like it might be possible to reconstruct it from those wireframes, under some mild assumptions to constrain the unknown camera.

Comment: Creating a similar mesh would be easy.  Creating similar bicubic patches would be feasible.  Neither would be (or be descended from) the model data Ed Catmull made in 1975, like the available data sets for the teapot, teaspoon, and teacup (links in my ask) are.  The historical significance of the possibly-lost-but-I-hope-not data is the point of the question.  But thx!

Comment: Well, if it was based off photogrammetry from these wireframes, it would indeed be "descended from" the original. Sometimes historians have to work from corrupted or incomplete versions of original sources; those still have value! But I understand the desire to find the original data if it is still extant. :)

Comment: FWIW according to [this ACM/SIGGRAPH article from 2006][1]: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1180098.1180128 

..the tea set is from Martin Newell, not Ed Catmull

"*Dr. Newell modeled and rendered this table setting scene, including a teapot, tea cups, saucers and spoons, and a milk pitcher, all on a table top with a draped curtain as a background. The Bézier control points of the teapot and other objects were made available within the close-knit DARPA-Net computer graphics research community .., "**
But i've had no luck finding the  milk jug either only the models you mentioned :-(

Comment: ::facepalm::  Yeah, that's what I get for working with Catmull's Elephant and Newell's Tea Set at the same time, especially since the Newell Teapot is often referred to as the Utah Teapot, and both of them are UU grads.  I've mixed them up on several posts on various sites -- every time I think I've fixed 'em all another pops up.  Especially embarrassing here since I recently edited this for the bounty.  Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: :-)
I think one thing that is probably certain... like the other models, there won't be a bottom on the milk jug ;-)